# Как в Android можно получить доступ к фонарику/вспышке камеры, если фонарик к данной камере не привязан?

Tags: java, android

В стандартном приложении "Камера" на телефоне можно включить вспышку/фонарик. При этом, когда я пытаюсь сделать это в своем приложении с помощью `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraID, true);` я получаю ошибку.

Вывод из debugger дает знать о том, что камера не обладает функцией вспышки:

```
boolean hasFlashForFrontCamera(CameraManager cManager) throws CameraAccessException {
        for(final String cameraId : cManager.getCameraIdList()){
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            boolean cFlash = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CameraID: "+cameraId);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CameraFlashInfo: "+cFlash);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Debugger:

```
I/: CameraID: 1
    CameraFlashInfo: false
```

Получается, в стандартном приложении "Камера" данная вспышка включается отдельно от камеры. Есть ли еще какой-то способ получить доступ к этому фонарику? Не через Camera или Camera2.

Comment: Возможно, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5503480) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939816) вы найдете ответ

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, конкретно в моем случае сделать уже ничего не получится. Написал в тех. поддержку Samsung и получил такой ответ:

> The front flashlight of Galaxy A6 is controlled with a Samsung
> specific method because it is not compatible with Android
> CameraManager. That's why you are not getting the front flashlight.

> This means that I can’t access it on my own in Android Studio?

> Yes, you can not use it on your app using Android Studio. Because it
> is not compatible with Android CameraManager. In the Samsung camera,
> it uses a Samsung specific method.